# Python: Static objects in a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, static

I was wondering how to properly keep a static object in a python class.
In this case I want to have a static dictionary

Just a simple example of what I'm looking for:

```
class dTest:
    # item I want to be static
    d = {"First":1}

>>> a = dTest()
>>> a.d
{'First': 1}
>>> dTest.d["Second"] = 2
>>> a.d["Third"] = 3
>>> a.d
{'Second': 2, 'Third': 3, 'First': 1}
>>> dTest.d
{'Second': 2, 'Third': 3, 'First': 1}
```

Now if I directly call the class and replace d with a new dictionary

```
>>> dTest.d = {}
>>> a.d
{}
```

However I'd also like to have the same functionality if I replace a.d with a new dictionary

```
>>> a.d = {"Fourth":4}
>>> a.d
{'Fourth': 4}
>>> dTest.d
{}
```

My desired result right now would be for dTest.d to be the same to a.d (dTest.d being {'Fourth': 4}).

Is there a proper practice for this, or do I have to just make sure I only ever edit the object if I do it from an instance of dTest?

Thanks!

Comment: use `property` to create getters and setters

Comment: Try changing `dTest.d` after you have changed `a.d` and you will notice that `a.d` will no longer change along with `dTest.d`.

Comment: @JBernardo : a property won't work when accessing `d` thru the class...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It will if created under a metaclass.

Comment: @JBernardo yes indeed that's a possible solution - even if possibly a bit overkill <g>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two different types of variables when dealing with classes: instance variables and class variables.

Class variables are accessible from all instances of a class, as well as the class itself:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    class_var = {'one': 1}
...
>>> Foo.class_var
{'one': 1}
>>> a, b = Foo(), Foo()
>>> a.class_var
{'one': 1}
>>> b.class_var
{'one': 1}
>>> a.class_var is b.class_var 
True # These are the same object
>>>
```

Instance variables are only accessible from the specific instance that they are assigned to:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.instance_var1 = {'two': 2}
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.instance_var2 = {'three': 3}
>>> foo.instance_var1
{'two': 2}
>>> foo.instance_var2
{'three': 3}
>>> Foo.instance_var1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'instance_var1'
```

Instance variables can *override* class variables:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     my_var = {'one': 1} # This a class variable
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.my_var = {'two': 2} # Override class my_var with instance my_var
>>> foo.my_var
{'two': 2}
>>> Foo.my_var
{'one': 1}
>>> foo.__class__.my_var # But you can still access the class variable like this.
{'one': 1}
>>>
```

To answer your question specifically. If you would like to alter the *class* variable, you must set it from the *class*, not the instance, so:

```
dTest.d = {'blah': 'blah'}
```

or

```
a.__class__.d = {'blah': 'blah'}
```

If you just do

```
a.d = {'blah': 'blah'}
```

You create an instance variable of `a` that shadows, or overrides the class variable with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary you are using within your class is shared, when you add key-value pairs to `d`, either with `a.d[key]=...` or `dTest.d[key]=...`, you don't change the reference of `d`, so it's still a shared class attribute.

But if you try to assign something to `a.d`, like `a.d=123` or `a.d=[11,22]`, you create an attribute `d` for instance `a`, and `a.d` no longer refers to `dType.d`. See [Assignment statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

*Note: If the object is a class instance and the attribute reference occurs on both sides of the assignment operator, the RHS expression, `a.x` can access either an instance attribute or (if no instance attribute exists) a class attribute. The LHS target `a.x` is always set as an instance attribute, creating it if necessary. Thus, the two occurrences of a.x do not necessarily refer to the same attribute: if the RHS expression refers to a class attribute, the LHS creates a new instance attribute as the target of the assignment:*

```
class Cls:
    x = 3             # class variable
inst = Cls()
inst.x = inst.x + 1   # writes inst.x as 4 leaving Cls.x as 3
```